# Laravel Controller doesn't get data from <input name="date" />

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I have two form page(views/sales/create.blade.php and views/purchases/create.blade.php). Both pages have input tag with name="date"

```
<input type="text" name="date" />
```

I have two controllers to handle those request that have the same line of code

```
public function store(Request $request){
   return "Date: " . $request->date;
}
```

The SalesController return the date, but the PurchaseController just return an empty string. By the way, I use datepicker for the date input. I copied the create.blade.php with minor modification, if the SalesController work, why the other not working?

One funny thing is, if I change the code to this:
views/purchases/create.blade.php:

```
<input type="text" name="date1" />
```

PurchaseController.php:

```
public function store(Request $request){
   return "Date: " . $request->date1;
}
```

It work just fine.

Comment: What minor modification you make ? 
Show us both forms to help you

Comment: are you getting other fields data?

Comment: please post full form code here

Comment: My mistake, on the purchase form there is another input with the same name="date", that's why I always get an empty date. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this , also you can refer [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests)

```
public function store(Request $request)
 {
    $date= $request->input('date');
    echo "Date =". $date;
 }
```